# Upgrading bootstrap-sass from v2.3.2.0 to v3.0.2.1 breaks sample_app CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, railstutorial.org

Working through Hartl's sample_app tutorial...not an issue with the tutorial, but with my own tinkering. Wondering if someone smarter than me can help us all out... I know that often times updating gems can bork your app(s), so I was prepared for this (hooray for committing often!), but when I saw that the bootstrap-sass gem I was using was out-of-date, I *had* to update.

Before the update, I was using v2.3.2.0 - no ill side effects.

After the update, the gem version was 3.0.2.1 and certain sass variables had changed, which was an easy fix (namely cameCase to non-camel-case). This was easily identified and fixed by running the rspec tests written to this point in the tutorial.

What's throwing me through the loop is now the right top menu links (home, help, sign in) look stacked like a "normal" un-styled un-ordered list. Correspondingly, this is causing the top bar to triple in size, and thus cover some of the text seen in the main content area.

I'm not a talented enough front-end guy to know exactly what is going on, but have tried to describe it as best as I can here. I can point you to the git commit compare [here](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/compare/v2.3.2.0...v3.0.2.1), but even this is a lot to take in.

In the meantime, I've reverted to v2.3.2.0 and all is back to how it was. Lesson learned, sniff out changes and test-test-test before blindly updating gems.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

P.S. I also have posted this in the /r/Learn_Rails subreddit [here](http://redd.it/1rer9n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list of what is different between BS 2.x and 3.x see this link: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration

If you want to use the latest BS version, you'll have to update the HTML to reflect the new class names etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the new functionality introduced in the newer version of Bootstrap(3.0) and tutorial is based on the bootstrap verison(2.3..).
So, If you are interested then see the changes made in the newer versions [Click Here](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/)